Unqualified MDX member names are not allowed in queries on DirectQuery models
tl;dr
What does this error message really mean?

There was an error communicating with Analysis Services. Please verify that the data source is available and your credentials are correct.  Unqualified MDX member names are not allowed in queries on DirectQuery models.


I want to create a Power BI paginated report that has 22 columns -- 20 dimensions and two measures.  There will be 16 optional parameters and 3 required parameters.
For a single, custom report, I would typically do this by creating a data source that directly connects to the database, creating a dataset by writing the SQL, then creating the layout.  But for report requirements that should follow a repeatable process, I was thinking it would be better to start with a curated semantic model that has already been published in Power BI.
I started on the web site by creating a paginated report from the semantic model.  But I found that I had no control over many aspects of the report, including no ability to add parameters.
After opening the report in Power BI Report Builder, I added the parameters, created some additional datasets to feed some of the parameters, etc.
At one point I took some action that caused Report Builder to completely wipe the main dataset that feeds the report output, so I used the Query Designer to develop the query logic - by just dragging the 22 columns onto the canvas and dragging the fields to the filter area and checking the parameter box.  There's nothing complicated or custom about the report logic.  How did I get Query Designer to generate invalid MDX?
I'm testing the report with parameters that should return 139 rows of output.
Trying to run the report in Power BI Report Builder (desktop app).  There is no message about invalid MDX.  The report eventually fails with a message that I have exceeded a 1,000,000 row limit.
Trying to run the report on the Power BI service showed "retrieving 505 rows", then produced this error:

There was an error communicating with Analysis Services. Please verify that the data source is available and your credentials are correct.  Unqualified MDX member names are not allowed in queries on DirectQuery models.

Any idea what is going on here?
Why does the desktop app fail at 1,000,000 rows when I asked for only 139?
Why does the online app fail with a message about invalid MDX?

Your model is in DQ mode, so you can only use DAX and not MDX to create queries.
Based on the documentation :

Client restrictions: When a model is in DirectQuery mode, it can only
be queried by using DAX. You cannot use MDX to create queries. This
means that you cannot use the Excel Pivot Client, because Excel uses
MDX.
However, you can create queries against a DirectQuery model in SQL
Server Management Studio if you use a DAX table query as part of an
XMLA Execute statement.


That explains the different error messages.  My report had apparently failed to successfully publish the last few attempts (but claimed success).  I finally got the DAX flavor of the report published and now I get the same message both on the web service and on the desktop client:  "The resultset of a query to external data source has exceeded the maximum allowed size of '1000000' rows."  That makes no sense since I'm asking for 139 rows.  I saw something like this years ago, but that was because I was using implicit measures.  This semantic model doesn't have that problem.

Can you execute your query on SSMS and try to check the results?

You mean run open SSMS and run DAX against against a Power BI Semantic Model that is published on the Power BI online service?

yes exactly try that. I am just curious what is the query you are trying to execute ?

I've never done that.  All I have ever run through SSMS is SQL against SQL databases.  So that I don't have to spend time trying to locate enough information to determine what steps are necessary, can you provide instructions or a link to the documentation for doing that?

You can use an XMLA endpoint, follow this guide : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-connect-tools

If you need more help you can contact me on Linkedin
